# Why does my modal open in the background?

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a modal in my angular 7 app using ng-bootstrap 4, but the modal component keeps opening in the background as a div, not as a modal. What am I doing wrong?

this is the component opening modal:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { AddPetModalComponent } from '../add-pet-modal/add-pet-modal.component';
import { Pet } from '../../models/pet';
import { PetsService } from '../../services/pets.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pets-list',
  templateUrl: './pets-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pets-list.component.less']      
})
export class PetsListComponent implements OnInit {

  petForm: FormGroup;
  pets: Pet[];
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private petService: PetsService,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
  ) { }

  openFormModal() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AddPetModalComponent);

    modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

modal component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-pet-modal',
  templateUrl: './add-pet-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-pet-modal.component.less']
})
export class AddPetModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.activeModal.close('Modal Closed');
  }

}
```

link to the module on github: https://github.com/Strzesia/Daily-Rat-Monitor/tree/fix/src/app/pets

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the app or of the DOM from the debugger and explain what really is the problem you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

I took a look around your code quickly and you seem to include essentials, I got it working though with no problems with this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-ng-bootstrap4-modal). Some pointers that might help you:

- In your app.module you are missing `entryComponents: [ AddPetModalComponent ]` as you are dynamically populating the modal with a component factory.
- It could be the minified bootstrap CSS that might messing with you, test to put in your index.html in the beginning the CDN as in the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-ng-bootstrap4-modal) example and see if it helps.
- remove your node_modules and re-install dependencies

Hope some of the points help!